# How do I get Contact number + name when app is launched from 'complete action using (sms app)' screen?

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I have recently discovered how to launch my sms app from the 'Complete Action Using' screen when selecting send sms from within the devices main contacts screen,

but I am having difficulty taking any details from the contact that I selected I want to send the message to, and placing those details (Phone number & Recipient name) into an edit text box,

If anyone could possibly tell me how to make my app take the recipients details on startup and place them in the appropriate EditText/TextView boxes I would be very appreciative thanx in advanced.

PS, I'm not sure if this matters but I'll mention anyway, my app is made to work with Android 2.1+ so I aren't to worried about pre-2.1 compatability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, sooo to get the Phone number I have used the following code

```
String phoneNumber = getIntent().getDataString();
```

But I'm still struggling to find out how to get the selected contacts name :\